# add day to current date

Tags: php, date

add a day to date, so I can store tomorrow's date in a variable.

```
$tomorrow = date("Y-m-d")+86400;
```

I forgot.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`date` returns a string, whereas you want to be adding 86400 seconds to the timestamp. I think you're looking for this:

```
$tomorrow = date("Y-m-d", time() + 86400);
```

Comment: Indeed, this will fail due to daylight saving. You should never write arithmetic like this.

Comment: Agreed that this fails to account for DST. I just answered based on whatever OP was trying to do, whether or not that's really what he wants is up to him to decide.

Comment: @Matchu's answer from below should at the very least be the accepted answer.

Comment: $date = 2.5 * 24 * 60 * 60;
$newDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time() + $date);
Date and time

Answer (score 37):

I'd encourage you to explore the PHP 5.3 [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) class.  It makes dates and times far easier to work with:

```
$tomorrow = new DateTime('tomorrow');

// e.g. echo 2010-10-13
echo $tomorrow->format('d-m-Y');
```

Furthermore, you can use the `+ 1 day` syntax with any date:

```
$xmasDay = new DateTime('2010-12-24 + 1 day');
echo $xmasDay->format('Y-m-d'); // 2010-12-25
```

Answer (score 26):

`date()` returns a string, so adding an integer to it is no good.

First build your tomorrow timestamp, using [`strtotime`](http://php.net/strtotime) to be not only clean but more accurate (see Pekka's comment):

```
$tomorrow_timestamp = strtotime("+ 1 day");
```

Then, use it as the second argument for your `date` call:

```
$tomorrow_date = date("Y-m-d", $tomorrow_timestamp);
```

Or, if you're in a super-compact mood, that can all be pushed down into

```
$tomorrow = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+ 1 day"));
```

Comment: +1 but a nicer way to build the timestamp would be `strtotime("+ 1 day");` because of DST

Answer (score 6):

Nice and obvious:

```
$tomorrow = strtotime('tomorrow');
```

Comment: Neat, but, in its current form, doesn't seem to match the OP's requirements :/ Add in that `date` call and we're good to go.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `add` method `datetime` class.
Eg, you want to add one day to current date and time.

```
$today = new DateTime();
$today->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
```

Further reference [php datetime add](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I find `mktime()` most useful for this sort of thing. E.g.:

```
$tomorrow=date("Y-m-d", mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"), date("d")+1, date("Y")));
```