# PHP string date + 1 day equals?

Tags: php, date

I have a date which is saved in a regular string.

```
// format = DD-MM-YYYY    
$date = "10-12-2011";
```

How can I get the date-string +1 day so: 11-12-2011?

Comment: possible duplicate of [add day to current date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3918646/add-day-to-current-date)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

[Similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286265/adding-1-day-to-a-datetime-format-value)

```
$date = date('d-m-Y', strtotime("+1 day", strtotime("10-12-2011")));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to overwrite $date, Aaron's answer works great. But if you need the new day saved into a separate variable as I did, this works:

```
$date = strtotime('10-12-2011'); // your date
$newDate = date('d-m-Y', strtotime("+1 day", $date)); // day after original date
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be using [`DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class for working with dates. Using `strtotime()` might not be the best choice in the long run.

To add 1 day to the data using DateTime you can use [`modify()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php) method.

```
$newDate = date_create_from_format('d-m-Y', $date)
    ->modify('+1 day')
    ->format('d-m-Y');
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want today `+$i day`

```
$today = date('Y-m-d');
$tomorrow = strtotime($today." +".$i." day");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use [the date function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to piece the date together manually (will obviously require to check for leap years, number of days in current month etc) or get [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and convert what you get via the date function parsing the timestamp you got from strtotime as the second argument.