# Auto increase min max date

Tags: php, html

Here's the code

```
input type="date" name="date" min="2016-12-28"
```

How can I auto increase my min date? so that tomorrow's min date is set to 2016-12-29 and so on. I don't want to keep setting the min date inside the html codes manually.

Comment: So how do you go from `2016-10-28` today to `2016-12-29` tomorrow? That's 2 months in difference there. What's the requirement, how many days from today should it be?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [add day to current date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3918646/add-day-to-current-date)

Comment: my mistake..i mean 2016-12-28 today to 2016-12-29 tomorrow

Comment: So 15 days in the future, always? Then simply do `min="<?php echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+15 days")); ?>"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use date() function of php.

```
<input type="date" name="date" min="<?php echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1days")); ?>">
```

Comment: This gives him the date. But not the date of yesterday.

As in my comment... There is the answer.